# Why closing p:dialog is reloading the page

Tags: jsf, primefaces

```
<p:dialog header="#{bundle['ref.details']}" id="detailsDial"
                    widgetVar="detailsDialog" style="max-width:800px">
                    <p:button value="#{bundle['close']}"
                        onclick="PF('detailsDialog').hide()" />
                </p:dialog>
```

There are not other form around the dialog, there is not form inside the dialog. Here is something very little that I miss but what. I don't know what other information to give because really don't understand how p:button would reload the page being client side only? There is not javascript included. Also there aren't error messages in the firebug console. Outside I'm using template like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:body>
<ui:composition template="/maintemplate.xhtml">
<ui:define name="content">
<p:dialog ....
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move from `p:button` to `p:commandButton` command button uses partial request by default

```
            <p:dialog header="#{bundle['ref.details']}" id="detailsDial"
                widgetVar="detailsDialog" style="max-width:800px">
                  <p:commandButton value="#{bundle['close']}" onclick="PF('detailsDialog').hide();" type="button" />
            </p:dialog>
```

---

To understand the difference it is enough to see the HTML being rendered in one or the other case, so for

```
<p:button value="Close" onclick="PF('detailsDialog').hide()" />
```

the rendered HTML is

```
<button type="button" onclick="PF('detailsDialog').hide();window.open('/ui/button.jsf','_self')" >
  <span class="ui-button-text ui-c">Close</span>
</button>
```

button does GET requests, notice the `window.open('/ui/button.jsf','_self')`

for `<p:commandButton value="Close" onclick="PF('detailsDialog').hide()" />`

the rendered HTML is

```
<button onclick="PF('detailsDialog').hide();PrimeFaces.ab({s:'j_idt19'});return false;" type="submit">
  <span class="ui-button-text ui-c">CloseCommandButton</span>
</button>
```

notice the `PrimeFaces.ab({s:'j_idt19'});return false;` so it sends a partialUpdate instead of submitting the enclosing form

Comment: I've updated the answer to better reflect the difference, see my edit